# how to catch ostream exception on linux?

Tags: c++, ostream

My Linux C++ application crashing while writing strings into ostream object. 
My original application tries to create a very bigg string output and write all string output into a stream. while writing the string into ostream object, the application crashed. At first the the crash was happened in both windows and Linux.

Now the issue fixed in Windows environment (details below). but In Linux it is crashing.

Following is the sample c++ program, that will generate the same scenario.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <strstream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;
bool fillScreen(std::ostream&);

int main ()
{
    auto_ptr<ostrstream> screen(new ostrstream);
    bool succ = false;
    try
    {
        succ = fillScreen(*screen);
    }catch(std::exception &ex)
    {
        std::cerr << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
    if(succ)
    {
        std::cout << "SCREEN Content is : " << screen->str() << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "NOTHING ON SCREEN Object " << std::endl;
    }
}

bool fillScreen(ostream &scr)
{
    unsigned long idx = 0;
    scr.exceptions(std::ios::badbit);// throws exception in windows but not in Linux.
    while (idx++ < 999999999)
    {
        scr << "BLAHBLAHBLAH_BLAH_BLAHBLAHBLAH_BLAH BLAHBLAHBLAH_BLAH BLAHBLAHBLAH_BLAH_" << " : " ;
        scr << "BLAHBLAHBLAH_BLAH_BLAHBLAHBLAH_BLAH_BLAHBLAHBLAH_BLAH_BLAHBLAHBLAH_BLAH_BLAHBLAHBLAH_BLAH_BLAHBLAHBLAH_BLAH_";
        scr << "BLAHBLAHBLAH_BLAH_BLAHBLAHBLAH_BLAH_BLAHBLAHBLAH_BLAH_BLAHBLAHBLAH_BLAH_BLAHBLAHBLAH_BLAH_BLAHBLAHBLAH_BLAH_"<< std::endl;   
        /*if(!(idx %100000))
        {
            std::cout << "Reached iteration: " << idx << std::endl;
        }*/
    }
    return true;
}
```

I have added following statement, in my program

```
screen.exceptions(std::ios::badbit);
```

With this statement, my programs not crashing in windows. 
While running on windows, the stream throws badbit exception and my application handle the exception and made a clean exit.

Output as follows,

Windows output: (run using cygwin)

```
$ ./overflow.exe
bad allocation
NOTHING ON SCREEN Object
```

Clean exit.

Linux Output:

```
[Mybuild@devlnx01 streamError]$ ./a.out
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
[Mybuild@devlnx01 streamError]$
```

Crashed - Not a clean exit. Even with exceptions set

```
screen.exceptions(std::ios::badbit);
```

Following is the stack trace taken using Linux gdb, (using core dump file)

```
Core was generated by `./a.out'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  std::strstreambuf::overflow (this=0x17f8018, c=72) at ../../.././libstdc++-v3/src/strstream.cc:174
174     ../../.././libstdc++-v3/src/strstream.cc: No such file or directory.
        in ../../.././libstdc++-v3/src/strstream.cc
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.x86_64
(gdb) where
#0  std::strstreambuf::overflow (this=0x17f8018, c=72) at ../../.././libstdc++-v3/src/strstream.cc:174
#1  0x00007eff6f4e7565 in std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::xsputn (this=0x17f8018, __s=<value optimized out>, __n=72)
    at /export/disk1/build/GCC4.5.3/gcc-4.5.3/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/streambuf.tcc:97
#2  0x00007eff6f4ddb85 in sputn (__out=..., __s=0x401038 "BLAHBLAHBLAH_BLAH_BLAHBLAHBLAH_BLAH BLAHBLAHBLAH_BLAH BLAHBLAHBLAH_BLAH_", __n=72)
    at /export/disk1/build/GCC4.5.3/gcc-4.5.3/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/streambuf:429
#3  __ostream_write<char, std::char_traits<char> > (__out=...,
    __s=0x401038 "BLAHBLAHBLAH_BLAH_BLAHBLAHBLAH_BLAH BLAHBLAHBLAH_BLAH BLAHBLAHBLAH_BLAH_", __n=72)
    at /export/disk1/build/GCC4.5.3/gcc-4.5.3/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/ostream_insert.h:48
#4  std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> > (__out=...,
    __s=0x401038 "BLAHBLAHBLAH_BLAH_BLAHBLAHBLAH_BLAH BLAHBLAHBLAH_BLAH BLAHBLAHBLAH_BLAH_", __n=72)
    at /export/disk1/build/GCC4.5.3/gcc-4.5.3/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/ostream_insert.h:99
#5  0x00007eff6f4dde0f in std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> > (__out=...,
    __s=0x401038 "BLAHBLAHBLAH_BLAH_BLAHBLAHBLAH_BLAH BLAHBLAHBLAH_BLAH BLAHBLAHBLAH_BLAH_")
    at /export/disk1/build/GCC4.5.3/gcc-4.5.3/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/ostream:513
#6  0x0000000000400d82 in fillScreen (scr=...) at overflow.cxx:35
#7  0x0000000000400c31 in main () at overflow.cxx:14
```

version and compiler details.

Windows 2008 (64bit) - VS2008

rhel62(64bit) gcc version 4.4.7 
Compilation arguments.
$g++ overflow.cxx -g3 -m64 -O0 -ggdb

In Windows it is exiting properly, But in Linux this is crashing with segmentation fault error.
All i am looking for is my application should do clean exit. i do not want it to exit with segmentation fault error.

I am not sure how to handle this in Linux, Can any one guide me on this.

Comment: try another compiler and get rid of the auto_ptr. This works with a modern compiler: http://ideone.com/42bhEJ (I've just copy-pasted your code).

Comment: `strstream` is obsolete and should never be used. The standard header is called `sstream`.

Comment: ostrstream is deprecated now, i have to use **ostringstream**. After applying ostringstream, program throws expected bad_alloc and do a clean exit.. (Special thanks to Alan, Lance and @DavidNorman :) ).

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an issue with the standard library shipping with your copy of `gcc` on linux.
Update your compiler (4.8.1 is the current version of gcc, as of 30. September 2013) and you'll get the expected behaviour as you can see in this [demo](http://ideone.com/42bhEJ).

Side note: `auto_ptr` shouldn't be used anymore. Use `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`. In this case, neither is necessary, drop the `new`.

Comment: Currently I cannot use 4.8.1 compiler on dev environment. but i have started using **ostringstream** in the code. Now the program throws exception and exiting properly.